# Log4net 1.2.10 running on .NET 1.1 and 2.0 not compatible

Tags: c#, log4net

I have old code that uses log4net version 1.2.10 targeted for the .NET 1.1 platform.
My current code uses lognet version 1.2.10 targeted for the .NET 2.0 platform

When I mix the old and new code all hell breaks loose. Code written today on .NET 4.0 and VS2010 can use the 2.0 log4net dll just fine.  but if I put in the 1.1 version, it breaks.  Conversely, the old dlls will break if I use the 2.0 log4net dll.

I do not want to force my old dlls onto 2.0.  Is there a good solution?  I guess what bugs me most is that the log4net has the same version number, but I cannot fool my code and dlls into working with a single version.

Answer (score 0):

Either a) grab the source and compile log4net to whatever target you want, or b) use ildasm a la [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLAssemblies.aspx) to change the dependency versions.